# how to get min number and max number in a set of non continuous number in R

Tags: r, numeric, minmax

I have a set of numbers: `1,2,3,7,8,9,12,13,14...` and I want to get the min and max in each continuous part so the result should be `1-3,7-9,12-14`.

I can use for loop to compare and get min max but this way takes me long time if I have over 10 million numbers...

does anybody know if there is a faster way to get what I want? 
thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, where do you get stuck? You can try playing with `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `diff` can help identify gaps. With that index we can split the vector and extract the first and last of each group:

```
c(sapply(split(x, cumsum(c(T, diff(x)>1))), function(v) c(v[1], tail(v,1)*-1)))
[1]   1  -3   7  -9  12 -14
```

---

The solution is golfed. To expand we can separate each call:

```
#Identify gaps in vector
changes <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) > 1L)

#Split vector on the above index
veclist <- split(x, changes)

#function to extract first item and the last item multiplied by -1
first_last <- function(v) c(v[1], tail(v,1)*-1)

#extract first and last from veclist
mat <- sapply(veclist, first_last)

#Remove list structure
c(mat)
[1]   1  -3   7  -9  12 -14
```